Data is not rendering from state in Reactjs

const DataManipulation = ({ data }) => {
  const [taskData, setTaskData] = useState([]);
  const subItemMaker = (subItem, task) => {
    subItem.forEach((sub) => {
      preconditionCheck(sub) &&
        setTaskData(addObjectToArray(taskData, task, sub));
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(taskData); //Printing the data here
  }, [taskData]);
  const makeUniqueProducts = (dataValues) => {
    dataValues.forEach((dataItem) => {
      subItemMaker(dataItem.subItemValues, dataItem.name);
    });
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    makeUniqueProducts(data); //Data changing function
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(taskData)} {/*Here it is not updating */}
    </>
  );
};
export default DataManipulation;

I am making a changes in the data and updating taskData state.
It is updating I can see in the useEffect but cant see in the render.
Please help me here.

Please include a [mre].

I guess your function is updating taskData multiple times within a loop so React may batch these updates for performance reasons. I'd do somtheing like this:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const DataManipulation = ({ data }) => {
  const [taskData, setTaskData] = useState([]);

  const addObjectToArray = useCallback((array, task, sub) => {
    return [...array, { task, sub }];
  }, []);

  const subItemMaker = useCallback((subItem, task) => {
// create a new array of items, then updates the state once with all new items.
    const newItems = subItem.reduce((acc, sub) => {
      if (preconditionCheck(sub)) {
        return addObjectToArray(acc, task, sub);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    setTaskData(prevTaskData => [...prevTaskData, ...newItems]);
  }, [addObjectToArray]);

  const makeUniqueProducts = useCallback((dataValues) => {
    dataValues.forEach((dataItem) => {
      subItemMaker(dataItem.subItemValues, dataItem.name);
    });
  }, [subItemMaker]);

  useEffect(() => {
    makeUniqueProducts(data);
  }, [data, makeUniqueProducts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(taskData);
  }, [taskData]);

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(taskData)}
    </>
  );
};

export default DataManipulation;

I used the functional form of setTaskData to ensure we're always working with the most up-to-date state.
